# How can I customize Electron border in specific event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, electron

I want to present the desktopCapturer windows and have the user select the window he/she wishes to share. Once the user selects that window, I want to put a border around that window in a color like green to indicate the window being shared. Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be implemented?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we can't customize the native window style so we can achieve your goal like this.

1. Create your BrowserWindow as [frameless](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md).
2. Create a border component inside your renderer.
3. Listening the mouseout and up event. And set this border color as green or remove based on the event.

Here is the code.

https://gist.github.com/626e49f002430d5a47b0d1e6b6ddee77

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the method suggested won't work because you can pick any window from the desktopCapturer picker window, not just renderer windows created by the Electron app.

Is there a solution that works on any window? This means there has to be a way to do this on Powerpoint windows, Word etc.

Comment: Oh, you are going to highlight the any window that will be selected... Hmm

Comment: Unfortunately, Electron doesn't provide any API to access the native windows.

Comment: You should use native platform APIs